# SQl database error _id does not exist?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I keep getting this error in my debug log.

> 07-10 04:48:43.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(477): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _id: , while compiling: SELECT _id, title, descrip, date, time, type

With this code.. I tried changing  the database name. and still it still gives the error.

```
class TaskHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "windowShopper";
  private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION = 1;

  public TaskHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE task (_id   INTEGER   PRIMARY   KEY    AUTOINCREMENT, 
                                   title TEXT, 
                                   descrip TEXT, 
                                   date TEXT, 
                                   time TEXT, 
                                   type TEXT);");
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE task (_id   INTEGER   PRIMARY   KEY    AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT, descrip TEXT, date TEXT, time TEXT, type TEXT)");
}
```

The extra semi-colon is probably killing the execution.